# Moving my folder from Desktop to Downloads (Folder)

Tags: directory, mv, removing

I tried to move a folder from my Desktop into my Downloads folder several times, all my tries end up with renaming my folder name only.
ex:
tuxedo@cosmos:~/Desktop$ **sudo mv myFolder Downloads**

- I don't want to rename, all what I want to move it to Downloads (folder )directly.

Comment: along to @Rinzwind answer , I was wondering : is there a real usage of "sudo" ? plus why use relative path , when you could use absolute path , if you are not sure ? i.e.:  /home/$USER/Downloads/ or ~/Downloads/

Comment: Absolutely don't use `sudo` except for system administration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `/` and a `../`:

```
tuxedo@cosmos:~/Desktop$ sudo mv myFolder ../Downloads/
```

The `../` is needed to go 1 directory up and then into Downloads. The way you do it is move it INSIDE Desktop and not to /home/$USER/Downloads/ (that is 1 directory up at the same level as Desktop).

The `/` makes it look for a directory and will move myFolder into Downloads/.  It can be used as a safeguard for `mv`: it will error if it can not find the directory.